# Strange error with "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64" message

Tags: c++

Although have some questions with the same title but, I believe that my problems are little different.

I have 3 files: main.cpp, car.h and car.cpp.

**main.cpp:**

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "car.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    Car v;
    std::cout << v.getName() << std::endl;
    return 0;
};
```

**car.h**

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

#ifndef CAR_H
#define CAR_H

class Car {
    public:
        std::string getName();
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**car.cpp**

```
#include "car.h"

std::string Car::getName() {
    return "blah";
};
```

When i run in terminal with "g++ main.cpp", i got this strange message:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Car::getName()", referenced from:
      _main in main-b1d04e.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see 
invocation)
```

It's a newbie question, but could anyone help me?

Comment: Try `g++ main.cpp car.cpp -o car`. Your result will be in the binary `car`.

Comment: @Kupiakos This is fantastic. Thank you very much, I spent all day in this problem without answers. Why does this problem occur, and why should I compile passing these parameters?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: Tank you so much!

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12573816/1530134) for info on what the actual problem is. On the parameters, you need to provide both `.cpp` files to `g++` to allow them to both compile and reference each other. The `-o` flag specifies where to put the output. Otherwise, it would just write to `a.out`.

Comment: This is the specific answer you should read: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12574400/1530134